# Reset System.Diagnostics.Metrics.ObservableGauge

Tags: c#, .net, prometheus, metrics, open-telemetry

I'm wondering if there are any ways to clear or reset an existing `ObservableGauge` in System.Diagnostics.Metrics.

Let me explain my issue. I created an `ObservableGauge` with the parameter `observeValues`, which is a `Func<IEnumerable<Measurement<T>>>`. Then, I generated an `IEnumerable<Measurement<T>>` from my dictionary and added some values to it. Prometheus picked up these values, but even after I cleared my dictionary, the metrics endpoint still returned them. Can someone please tell me how to reset these metrics?

```
public static void CreateCounters(ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> registry)
{
    Meter.CreateObservableGauge("registry_total", () => GetCount(registry));
}

private static IEnumerable<Measurement<int>> GetCount(ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> registry)
{
    return registry.Select(kv =>
        new Measurement<int>(kv.Value, new KeyValuePair<string, object?>("region", kv.Key)));
}
```

Sure, I could set all the values to 0 manually. However, this would make the code more complex and there would be items in dictionary which not interesting to me anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak specifically to the Prometheus Exporter, but I experienced a similar behavior with the OpenTelemetry ConsoleExporter. After a lot of research and a lot of dead ends, I found this [GitHub OpenTelemetry Discussion Thread 4412](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/discussions/4412).

That thread contains this explanation:

> It looks like you're using ConsoleExporter which by default has a
> TemporalityPreference as Cumulative and not Delta. With Cumulative
> aggregation temporality, the MetricReader (ConsoleExporter in this
> case) would keep exporting the cumulated data for the metric with
> every collection. **Metrics are reported for a certain duration.**

I wish it expounded on the "certain duration." But, it doesn't.

Using what I learned from that thread, I solved my problem by initially configuring my exporter like this:

```js
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .WithMetrics(metrics =>
        metrics.AddMeter("MyNameSpace.*")
            .AddConsoleExporter((o, m)
                => { m.PeriodicExportingMetricReaderOptions.ExportIntervalMilliseconds = 60000;
                     m.TemporalityPreference = MetricReaderTemporalityPreference.Delta; })
                     
// Where:
// o = OpenTelemetry.Exporter.ConsoleExporterOptions
// m = OpenTelemetry.Metrics.MetricReaderOptions
```

My external metrics store exporter also accepts the MetricReaderOptions. Perhaps the Prometheus Exporter does as well.

After adding that, my ObservableGauge metrics get exported to the console once. By the time the 60-second export interval comes around again, they have been cleared (if no new observations have been made).